# Error can't call and get id from other javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<?php
<input type="hidden" value="1" />
<input type="submit" id="button" value="submit">
?>
```

in file script.js I using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();
       alert(id);
       return false;
    });
});
```

> When using srcipt.js get id from index.php is result "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
var id = $(this).prev('input:hidden').val();
```

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/MNDrg/

Comment: Just wondering, why the prev filter? `$(this).prev` will never return more than 1 element, assuming `this` is a DOM element.

Comment: @Esailija, 'Just based it on the html provided.

Answer (score 1):

$(this) is referring to the button itself.

If you need to do it this way, you can use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        console.log(this);
       var id = $(this).parent().find('input:hidden').val();
       alert(id);
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find` will only look for elements nested within.

If you need to find all input:hidden on the same level, use `$(this).parent().find('input:hidden')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only one hidden field, You could just use `$('input:hidden')`
`$(this)` is not absolutely necessary here.

If there are more *than one* you might consider adding ID to each hidden field and refer to it individually.